# Create UV Set with openmaya API 2.0

Tags: python, nodes, maya, uv-mapping

Im writing a custom reader node for maya (in python with openmaya API 2.0) and I would like to send my uv sets to a regular maya mesh node.

Im wondering what would be the best way to push the uv sets in a mesh node? I wasn't able to find what data I have to create and how to send them to the mesh node.

My reader is a `OpenMaya.MPxNode` who push custom data to a `OpenMaya.MPxSurfaceShape`. The shape is linked by out mesh / in mesh plugs to a regular maya mesh. I attempt to fill the uvSet plug of this shape using `compute` but without success. I expect the UVSets to be sent to the mesh.

The following code sample is a limited test where my only goal is to create a new UVSet and attach it to the mesh.

Any ideas or documentation which could help?
I tried several things but I **always** get the error below.

**The error:**

```
// Error: (kFailure): Object does not exist
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/path/to/maya/plug-ins/test_create_uv_set.py", line 60, in compute
#     mesh.createUVSet("toto")
# RuntimeError: (kFailure): Object does not exist //
```

**The running code:**

```
"""
usage

import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

cmds.loadPlugin("/path/to/maya/plug-ins/test_create_uv_set.py")

transform_node = pm.polySphere(n='transform1', ch=1, o=1, r=4)[0]
mesh1_node = transform_node.getShape()
pm.setAttr(mesh1_node + ".visibility", False)
uv_set_mod_node = pm.createNode("uvSetModifier", name="uvsetmodifier1")
mesh2_node = pm.createNode("mesh", name="mesh2", parent=transform_node)
pm.hyperShade(assign="initialShadingGroup")

pm.Attribute.connect(mesh1_node.attr("outMesh"), uv_set_mod_node.attr("inMesh"))
pm.Attribute.connect(uv_set_mod_node.attr("outMesh"), mesh2_node.attr("inMesh"))
"""

import sys
import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


def maya_useNewAPI():
    pass


class uvSetModifier(OpenMaya.MPxNode):
    typeName = "uvSetModifier"
    id = OpenMaya.MTypeId(0xCCCCC)

    inMesh = None
    outMesh = None

    @staticmethod
    def creator():
        return uvSetModifier()

    @staticmethod
    def initialize():
        typedAttr = OpenMaya.MFnTypedAttribute()

        uvSetModifier.inMesh = typedAttr.create("inMesh", "im", OpenMaya.MFnData.kMesh)
        typedAttr.writable = True
        OpenMaya.MPxNode.addAttribute(uvSetModifier.inMesh)

        uvSetModifier.outMesh = typedAttr.create("outMesh", "om", OpenMaya.MFnData.kMesh)
        typedAttr.writable = True
        OpenMaya.MPxNode.addAttribute(uvSetModifier.outMesh)

    def __init__(self):
        OpenMaya.MPxNode.__init__(self)

    def compute(self, plug, datablock):
        if plug == uvSetModifier.outMesh:
            inputData = datablock.inputValue(uvSetModifier.inMesh)
            outputData = datablock.outputValue(uvSetModifier.outMesh)
            outputData.setMObject(inputData.asMesh())
            mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(inputData.asMesh())
            mesh.createUVSet("toto")
            datablock.setClean(plug)


def initializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMaya.MFnPlugin(obj, "Autodesk", "3.0", "Any")

    try:
        plugin.registerNode(uvSetModifier.typeName, uvSetModifier.id, uvSetModifier.creator, uvSetModifier.initialize)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to register node\n")
        raise


def uninitializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMaya.MFnPlugin(obj)

    try:
        plugin.deregisterNode(uvSetModifier.id)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write("Failed to deregister node\n")
        pass
```

**UPDATE 1: THEODOX input**

I added the following line (59)

```
if inputData.asMesh() is not None:
   print "test"
   mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh(inputData.asMesh())
   mesh.createUVSet("toto")
```

**results**: I still get the same error message

Comment: Are you getting the error before connecting something to the node? You're not null checking before proceeding, so it might be trying to run when inputData.asMesh() is returning `none`

Comment: @SKYnine Please do the check and update the status here

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help. I described results in an edit and get the same error message